# Union of 2 named_scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following 2 named_scopes:

```
  named_scope :scope1,  lambda { |pi_id|
    { :select => "DISTINCT REF_PRO.*",
      :joins => "INNER JOIN LNK_PRO ON  LNK_PRO.PR_PRO_FK = REF_PRO.RPR_ID 
                 INNER JOIN EMI_SUBMISSION on EMI_SUBMISSION.SUB_ID =  LNK_PRO.PR_SUBMISSION_FK
                 INNER JOIN EMI_PERSON on EMI_PERSON.PER_ID = EMI_SUBMISSION.SUB_PI_FK ",
      :conditions=>["EMI_PERSON.PER_ID = ? ", pi_id],
      :group => "REF_PRO.RPR_ID"

    }
  }


  named_scope :scope2, lambda { |pi_id|
    { :select => "REF_PRO.*",
      :joins => "INNER JOIN REF_USER ON REF_USER.USR_ID = REF_PRO.RPR_CREATED_BY 
                 INNER JOIN LNK_USER_PI on LNK_USER_PI.USP_USER_FK = REF_USER.USR_ID ",
      :conditions=>["LNK_USER_PI.USP_PI_ID = ? ", pi_id]
    }
  }
```

I need to join their results.

Is there a way of doing a union of the 2 resultsets? If not, how can I modify one named_scope so that it returns me the combined results of the above named scopes?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Chaining scopes always narrows the search results. And ARel has yet to address the problem of unions, afiak. There are some hacks out there. Or, and you probably thought of this already, you could just concatenate the results of each scope and call `.uniq` on it. Not very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Model.scope1+Model.scope2
```